# how to call a public function inside child form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

i am having a toolstrip in the mdi form which contains save, update delete and clear buttons.
the child form is having save , update , delete and clear as public sub routines , and client form will not have any standard buttons,  i will click the respective button in the parent tool window which should call the child forms function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates and events to do so. Define a delegate and an event in child form, define their handlers in parent form and call these handlers on click of the menus in parent form.

Comment: any examples would be greatful